# Newtonsoft Json deserializer not working correctly

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am building an application that handles surveys for people to fill in, in a C# environment.

When I run the application normally, everything works fine, the deserialize works, the serialize works, everything works.

When I send a survey, everything again goes fine. When i re-open the application, the program automatically sends a request to the server to retrieve the surveys available. But when he tries to deserialize the json, he sees he needs to make 2 sub objects but does not fill them.

I checked to see if the json I was getting was correct, and it is. The problem seems that the deserialize doesn't know where the data has to go (even though he normally works with the exact same method).

What I get instead is:

- root: This is the base variable and is null untill it gets filled. So I know the deserialize is doing something.
- newSurvey: Created by the deserialize, but does not get filled (stays null)
- result: Created by the deserialize, but does not get filled (stays null)

The json looks like this (please keep in mind I kept the data itself out and it is a stripped down version):

```
{
"id": "data",
"name": "data",
"description": "data",
"surveyVersion": "data",
"welcomeMessage": "data",
"exitMessage": "data",
"anonymousAnswers": false,
"publicationDate": "data",
"expirationDate": "data",
"serverInstanceName": "data",
"documentVersion": "data",
"questions": [
    {
        "id": "data",
        "position": 0,
        "text": "data",
        "answerRequired": true,
        "dependsOn": null,
        "dependencyType": null,
        "dependencyParameter": null,
        "choices": null,
        "type": {
            "name": "data",
            "hasChoices": false,
            "multipleAnswersPossible": false
        },
        "defaultValue": null,
        "openOption": null,
        "maxOpenOption": null,
        "maxCharacters": "data",
        "minimumAnswers": null,
        "maximumAnswers": null,
        "answers": null,
        "openAnswers": null
    }
]}
```

I checked the json using http://jsonlint.com/ and it is correct, I also checked the data manually and it contains all the data I need.

Now I don't know how I can make sure he deserializes normally if he doesn't want to do this. If I did not send a survey, everything works fine, this only happens after I send a survey and restart the application.

code where the error occurs:

```
if (jSONSurvey != "") {
            if (newSurveys != null) {
                var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject> (jSONSurvey);
                if (root.newSurveys != null)
                    newSurveys = root.newSurveys;
            } else {
                newSurveys = new List<NewSurvey> ();
                var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject> (jSONSurvey);
                if (root.newSurveys != null)
                    newSurveys = root.newSurveys;
            }
```

The crash part is the else statement.

Comment: do you have a code example that shows where the error comes from?

Comment: the Json you've posted is missing some `}` is this a typo?

Comment: In fact it's just not valid json at all.

Comment: @Liam It is possible I mis wrote it, but I can't show the actual JSON, All I can say is that the actual Json is correct.

Comment: what's a RootObject? You've spent a lot of time writing this out but seem to of missed almost all the information needed to answer the question.

Comment: If you put that Json in jsonLint, it's invalid. Without the exact json structure (even missing out the data) any answer will be a guess.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to be as informative as possible. The RootObject is a container class that holds the surveys and the response data. Those are in turn classes that contain variables where the deserializer stores the data from the survey.

Comment: @Liam I stripped down one of the jsons as much as possible. That is the basic setup. Hope it helps.

Comment: The `RootObject` class does not appear to match the structure of the supplied data. There is no `NewSurveys` or `result` property in the data.

Comment: Yes, what @Kami said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RootObject` class structure appears not to match the supplied data.

Try something like this to debug if it's the class or conversion that is failing.

```
 var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jSONSurvey);
 Console.WriteLine(root.id);
```

If the root object is populated with data, then the structure of your `RootObject` class does not allow for the properties.

Comment: This did indeed make me find the problem, cheers. Even though the body of the JSON was the same and correct, it missed out some naming before the body itself.